# How to preserve a JSON object with triple quotes when reading it in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, elasticsearch, opensearch

When reading JSON queries with triple quotes, Python converts the `"""` to `'`. For example, in this Elasticsearch query:

```
query = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "responses.counts": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.responses = ['error':0L,'success':0L,'other':0L]",
        "map_script": """
              def code = doc['response.keyword'].value;
                 if (code.startsWith('5') || code.startsWith('4')) {
                  state.responses.error += 1 ;
                  } else if(code.startsWith('2')) {
                   state.responses.success += 1;
                  } else {
                  state.responses.other += 1;
                }
             """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The function inside `map_script` gets completely distorted. How do I store this JSON object (serialize) so it can be correctly passed on to elasticsearch?

Comment: Triple quotes are just synttactic sugar to create strings with new lines and white space more easily. The resulting string you get still has those new lines and white space. If something is not working for you, make a [mcve]